# CSS3 animation - changing words to infinity without rewind

Tags: css, css-animations

It's my first time experimenting with css3 animations and I have a question regarding the following setup:

[Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ynGFJ)

After `item3` the animation rewinds to `item1`. I wonder if it's possible to let follow the `item1` after the `item3` without this rewinding, so that `item3` also moves to the top and `item1` slides in from the bottom again, and so on and on?

**HTML**

```
<div id="change">
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item2</span>
  <span>item3</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#change {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 58px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
}

#change span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  animation: myAnim 10s ease infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: myAnim 10s ease infinite 0s;
}


@keyframes myAnim {
  0% { top: 0px; }
  20% { top: 0px; }
  35% { top: -58px; }
  55% { top: -58px; }
  70% { top: -116px; }
  90% { top: -116px; }
  100% { top: 0px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myAnim {
  0% { top: 0px; }
  20% { top: 0px; }
  35% { top: -58px; }
  55% { top: -58px; }
  70% { top: -116px; }
  90% { top: -116px; }
  100% { top: 0px; }
}
```

Comment: Event listeners don't work in my browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. If we were using an image, you could easily just take advantage of `repeat` and force the beginning of the element to start at the end of the element. However, since we aren't using an image, the only solution I can think of would be to use the first element as the last element.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aCdIz)

**HTML**

```
<div id="change">
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item2</span>
  <span>item3</span>
  <span>item1</span> <!-- The first element is used as the last element-->
</div>
```

**Modified CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes myAnim {
  0% { top: 0; }
  20% { top: 0; }
  35% { top: -58px; }
  55% { top: -58px; }
  70% { top: -116px; }
  90% { top: -116px; }
  100% { top: -172px; }
}
```

Comment: ok, thank you so far. maybe not a "clean" solution, but it works fine and is easy to set up.

i just had another idea, i will try if it works and than post it here.

Comment: @user2446980 I agree, it's not really the cleanest, but it works. I thought you might be interested in this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bbmol) it's based on the answer you posted, but I fixed the first element. 1+

Answer (score 1):

it didn't let me rest, so i figured out another solution. with no doubled item1, but the missing part in this is that it doesn't start with the item1 being already there at the beginning.

[Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nFmwB)

**HTML**

```
<div id="change">
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item2</span>
  <span>item3</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#change {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 58px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
}

#change span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  animation: myAnim 9s ease infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: myAnim 9s ease infinite 0s;
}

#change span:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  top: 58px;
}

#change span:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  top: 58px;
}

@keyframes myAnim {
  0% { top: 58px;  }
  15% { top: 0px; }
  33% { top: 0px; }
  48% { top: -58px; opacity:1; }
  60% { top: -58px; opacity: 0; }
  80% { top: 58px; opacity: 0; }
  100% { top: 58px; opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myAnim {
  0% { top: 58px;  }
  15% { top: 0px; }
  33% { top: 0px; }
  48% { top: -58px; opacity:1; }
  60% { top: -58px; opacity: 0; }
  80% { top: 58px; opacity: 0; }
  100% { top: 58px; opacity: 1; }
}
```