# JavaScript Event Firing But Not Updating DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

While trying to solve a problem for someone on StackOverflow ([specifically here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208700/css3-animation-changing-words-to-infinity-without-rewind)) I started playing around with JavaScript event listeners for CSS3 transitions. The HTML/CSS is simple, I setup a div containing 3 list items and let CSS rotate through them along with another div for placing new elements via javascript.

[Here is a link to the code itself](http://codepen.io/Crackerz/pen/liJLp)

HTML

```
<div id="list">
    <span class="element">item1</span>
    <span class="element">item2</span>
    <span class="element">item3</span>
</div>

<div id="test">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.change {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 58px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.change span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  animation: myAnim 10s ease infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: myAnim 10s ease infinite 0s;
}


@keyframes myAnim {
  0% { top: 0px; }
  20% { top: 0px; }
  35% { top: -58px; }
  55% { top: -58px; }
  70% { top: -116px; }
  90% { top: -116px; }
  100% { top: 0px; }
}
```

Something interesting happens with the JavaScript however. I have a single listener registered for `animationiteration` on my list, and the function called adds a single element to the test div. The issue is the elements appended to the list appear in groups of 3 after the animation resets back to 1! It appears as if the function has been called 3 times, but it only renders to the DOM every 3 calls. Why is this happening?

JavaScript

```
function listener(e) {
  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  var child = document.createElement('div');
  child.innerHTML = "test";
  document.getElementById("test").appendChild(child);

}

var change = document.getElementById("list");
change.addEventListener("animationiteration", listener, false);
change.className = "change";
console.log(change);
```

System information:

```
Firefox Version 27.0.1
ArchLinux
```

Note that the demo only works in Firefox

**Update 1**

I put a breakpoint on line 40 of index.html (where the JavaScript resides) and I confirmed that `listener` is indeed called AFTER all 3 animations and is called 3 times at that point (one for each iteration). So now the question is, why does it behave like this?

Comment: :O yo when full iteration gets complete then only it update the DOM .. strange.. !

Comment: I think animiteration event capture whenever animloop finish like anim is to spin 360  degree then it will capture after 1 full spin finish. defined keyframe anim is 1 cycle so if u say infinite then as per keyframe 1 anim cycle finish that is iteration finish and it will call the callback.

Comment: @neha, then why did it add 3 elements at once like it had been called 3 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there's 3 spans within #list, each getting the animation. Try just adding a fourth span and 4 "test" messages will come up. According to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/animationiteration) "animationiteration" bubbles so attaching the listener to the parent will fire as many times as there are children that match the selector